Find the area of the region enclosed by $\frac{\sin x}{\sin y}=\frac{\sin x+\sin y}{\sin(x+y)}$ and the $x$-axis.
Here is the graph of $\dfrac{\sin x}{\sin y}=\dfrac{\sin x+\sin y}{\sin(x+y)}$.


Find the area of the region enclosed by the curve and the $x$-axis, from $x=0$ to $x=\pi$.

Where the question came from, and why I think the answer is $\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}$
This question arose when I asked myself: "A triangle's vertices are three uniformly random points on a circle. The side lengths are, in random order, $a,b,c$. The triangle inequality tells us that $P(a+b<c)=0$. But  what is $P\left(a+b<\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)c\right)$, given that $\frac{a}{b}>1$ ?"
(These kinds of questions often have rational probabilities, for example $P(ab<c^2)=\frac35$ as shown here; $P(\frac1a+\frac1b<\frac1c)=\frac15$ as shown here; for a unit circle $P(ab<c)=\frac12$ as shown here.)
I assumed that the circle is centred at the origin, and the vertices of the triangle are:
$A\space(\cos(-2y),\sin(-2y))$ where $0\le y<\pi$
$B\space(\cos(2x),\sin(2x))$ where $0\le x<\pi$
$C\space(1,0)$
I let:
$a=BC=2\sin x$
$b=AC=2\sin y$
$c=AB=|2\sin(x+y)|$
By symmetry, we only need to consider the region where $x+y<\pi$, so we can drop the modulus signs.
$P\left(a+b<\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)c\right)=P\left(\color{red}{\dfrac{\sin x}{\sin y}>\dfrac{\sin x+\sin y}{\sin(x+y)}}\right)$
Then I tried to express $y$ in terms of $x$, or $x$ in terms of $y$ (so that I could get an integral), but I failed. Wolfram is not helpful. I rotated the graph $45^\circ$ by letting $x\to x-y$ and $y\to x+y$, which gives $\frac{\tan x}{\tan y}=\frac{\cos x+\cos y}{\cos x-\cos y}$, but I still couldn't isolate $x$ or $y$. Wolfram is still not helpful.
A simulation of $10^7$ random triangles yielded a proportion of $0.49998$ satisfying $a+b<\frac{ac}{b}$ given that $\frac{a}{b}>1$, suggesting that the probability is $\frac12$. If so, then the area of the shaded region should be $\frac12\times\frac{\pi^2}{4}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{8}}\approx1.2337$.
(Now I am more interested in this area question, than the probability question.)
Update 1
Using the Wolfram link in @Masd's answer, I made a desmos graph of $y$ as a function of $x$. It looks just like the original curve, except it has gaps that I have been unable to bridge.

Here is the link to my desmos graph. If someone can bridge the gaps, then we can use desmos to integrate from $x=0$ to $x=\pi$, and see if the area could be $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$.
Update 2
@Masd's answer now reports a numerical integral of $1.23370055014$, which matches $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$ to $11$ decimal places. Is there a proof that the area is exactly $\frac{\pi^2}{8}$?

Did you start with the probability problem, or the area problem?

@AlexK I started with the probability problem.

Maybe a series expansion for $y$ can be found. Then, one can integrate

This doesn't make progress on the problem, but here is a tidier way to move between angles and side lengths. Let $x,y,z$ be a random triplet of positive angles summing to $\pi$. Then we can inscribe a triangle with these angles into a circle of radius 1; let $a,b,c$ be the sides which are opposite to $x,y,z$. The law of sines then immediately dictates$$\frac{a}{\sin x}=\frac{b}{\sin y}=\frac{c}{\sin z}=2$$ which gives the desired conversion.

@Semiclassical Using your method, to get the $2$ on the RHS I used the fact that the area of the triangle is $\frac{abc}{4}$. Is that how you got the $2$?

I used the method of "that's what the law of sines says". That said, whether the law of sines includes the RHS depends on the source. Both Wikipedia and Mathworld take the law to include the equality with $2R$ where $R$ is the radius of the circumcircle, but the version I saw in high school omitted this.

Posted on MO.

The answer is indeed $\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}$.
The proof is a combination of two answers at MO: @fedja's answer and @Iosif Pinelis' answer.

I really liked your intuition about the $\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}$ value of the area. I tried to achieve $y=f(x)$ but couldn't and so I decided to approximate the area as follows:
I determined the points $A, B$ and $C$ of the curve with which it was not difficult to calculate the area of the polygon $OABCF$ as the sum of the areas of the triangles $\triangle{OBF},\triangle{OBA}$ and $\triangle{BFC}$ (for the last two I calculated the points $D$ and $F$. The área it remains to have is very little and, of course, can be reduced of size if we iterate the same procedure. What I wanted to get was an approximation or an area greater than $\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}$ in which case your claim would have been rejected.
With our data, calculation gives for the area $A$ of the polygon $OABCF$
$$2A=0.64\times\pi+1.27263506159\times0.129495173655+2.13955616033\times0.0879317917479$$ $$A=1.18177720166$$ $$\frac{\pi^2}{8}-A=0.0519233484762\gt0$$ The area left to calculate is small. Note that the areas enclosed by the curve and the segments $OA$ and $CF$ are very small (they are almost not noticeable in the attached figure). I agree now with the OP's feeling. I hope it is true.


Changing coordinates
Let $R_\spadesuit$ be the region bounded by $y=0$ and $y=F(x)$ over the interval $x\in(0,\pi)$, where $y=F(x)$ satisfies
$$\frac{\sin x}{\sin y} = \frac{\sin x + \sin y}{\sin(x+y)} \tag{$\spadesuit$}$$
(i.e. the intimidating $\arcsin$ integrand in @Masd's post). We perform the following change of coordinates to rewrite and simplify $(\spadesuit)$ :
$$\begin{align*}
(X,Y) = \left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2}, \frac{-x+y}{\sqrt2}\right) &\iff (x,y) = \left(\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt2}, \frac{X+Y}{\sqrt2}\right) \tag1 \\ 
(u,v) = \left(\cos\frac X{\sqrt2}, \cos \frac Y{\sqrt2}\right) &\iff (X,Y) = \left(\sqrt2\,\arccos u, \sqrt2\,\arccos v\right) \tag2 \\
(s,t) = \left(\frac uv, \sqrt{\frac{1-v^2}{1-u^2}}\right) &\iff (u,v) = \left(s \sqrt{\frac{t^2-1}{s^2t^2-1}}, \sqrt{\frac{t^2-1}{s^2t^2-1}}\right) \tag3
\end{align*}$$
$(1)$ rotates $R_\spadesuit$ counterclockwise about the origin by $\dfrac\pi4$ rad and, using the angle sum/difference and Pythagorean identities, transforms $(\spadesuit)$ to
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin \frac{X-Y}{\sqrt2}}{\sin \frac{X+Y}{\sqrt2}} &= \frac{\sin\frac{X-Y}{\sqrt2} + \sin\frac{X+Y}{\sqrt2}}{\sin\left(\sqrt2\, X\right)} = \frac{\cos\frac Y{\sqrt2}}{\cos\frac X{\sqrt2}} \\
\implies & \frac{\cos\frac X{\sqrt2}}{\cos\frac Y{\sqrt2}} + \frac{1 + \frac{\cos\frac X{\sqrt2}}{\cos\frac Y{\sqrt2}}  \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos^2\frac Y{\sqrt2}}{1-\cos^2\frac X{\sqrt2}}}}{1 - \frac{\cos\frac X{\sqrt2}}{\cos\frac Y{\sqrt2}}  \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos^2\frac Y{\sqrt2}}{1-\cos^2\frac X{\sqrt2}}}} = 0 \tag{$\heartsuit$}
\end{align*}$$
Eliminate the trig expressions with $(2)$ to transform $(\heartsuit)$ to
$$\frac uv + \frac{1 + \frac uv \sqrt{\frac{1-v^2}{1-u^2}}}{1 - \frac uv \sqrt{\frac{1-v^2}{1-u^2}}} = 0 \tag{$\clubsuit$}$$
which motivates $(3)$ and reduces $(\clubsuit)$ to a trivial equation,
$$s + \frac{1+st}{1-st}  = 0 \tag{$\diamondsuit$}$$
Let $R_\heartsuit$, $R_\clubsuit$, and $R_\diamondsuit$ be the resp. regions obtained by applying the transformations listed above. I've plotted them in red below (arranged top-to-bottom, left-to-right). Solve $(\diamondsuit)$ for $t$ as a function of $s$ to recover an equation for one of the boundaries of $R_\diamondsuit$,
$$t(s) = \dfrac{s+1}{s(s-1)}$$



Determining boundaries of $R_\square$
The result of $(1)$ is straightforward, shifting the line $y=0$ to $Y=X$ and $y=F(x)$ to $Y=G(X)$. Admittedly, I'm eyeballing here and assuming that the rotated graph of $F$ is a single-valued function $G$, but I think this just boils down to showing $x > F(x)$ and $F'(x) < 1$. The vertices $(0,0)$ and $(0,\pi)$ in the $(x,y)$ plane correspond to $(0,0)$ and $\left(\dfrac\pi{\sqrt2},\dfrac\pi{\sqrt2}\right)$ in $(X,Y)$.
$(2)$ matches the lines $Y=X$ and $u=v$, while $G$ is transformed to another (presumably) single-valued function that permits us to write $v=H(u)$.
$(3)$ requires that $t\ge1$. Solving $t(s)=1$ we find $s=1\pm\sqrt2$, and we observe that $t(s)\stackrel{s\to1^+}\longrightarrow\infty$. Only the region to the right of the asymptote $s=1$ with the vertex at $\left(1+\sqrt2,1\right)$ has a finite area.

Computing the area
In terms of double integrals, the area we want to find is given by
$$\begin{align*}
\iint_{R_\spadesuit} dA &= \int_{x=0}^\pi \int_{y=0}^{F(x)} dy \, dx \\
\iint_{R_\heartsuit} dA &= \int_{X=0}^\tfrac\pi{\sqrt2} \int_{Y=X}^{G(X)} dY \, dX \\
\iint_{R_\clubsuit} dA &= \int_{u=0}^1 \int_{v=H(u)}^u \frac2{\sqrt{1-u^2}\sqrt{1-v^2}} \, dv \, du \\
\iint_{R_\diamondsuit} dA &= \int_{s=1}^{1+\sqrt2} \int_{t=1}^\tfrac{s+1}{s(s-1)} \frac2{s^2t^2-1} \, dt \, ds
\end{align*}$$
We wrap up by bridging the gap to the integral(s) evaluated in the linked MO post.
$$\begin{align*}
\int \frac 2{s^2t^2-1} \, dt &= -\frac2s \tanh^{-1}(st) + C \\
\implies \iint_{R_\diamondsuit} dA &= 2 \int_1^{1+\sqrt2} \left(\tanh^{-1}s - \tanh^{-1}\frac{s+1}{s-1}\right) \, \frac{ds}s \\
&= 2 \int_1^{1+\sqrt2} \tanh^{-1} \frac{1+2s-s^2}{1+s^2} \cdot \frac{ds}s \\
&= \boxed{\int_1^{1+\sqrt2} \log \frac{s+1}{s(s-1)} \cdot \frac{ds}s}
\end{align*}$$
by the identity $\tanh^{-1}\alpha\pm\tanh^{-1}\beta=\tanh^{-1}\dfrac{\alpha\pm\beta}{1\pm\alpha\beta}$.

Wonderful answer! I always find it difficult to change coordinates in multiple integrals (especially to find the new bounds), but you made it easier.

Thanks so much @Zacky! I had a feeling there was a more manageable path to the log integral, and I'm glad that suspicion panned out. Not too happy about the hand-waving bit, however...
